# Is it possible to configure Azure C# function DocumentDB attribute arguments?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm building an Azure Http triggered C# function with an output binding to Cosmos DB. My function definition is like this:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "myroute")]HttpRequestMessage req,
                                              [DocumentDB("database", "collection", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] IAsyncCollector<dynamic> document,
                                              TraceWriter log)
```

This works fine.

However, I would like to be able to configure the *database* and *collection* names in the DocumentDB attribute, but if I try something like:

```
[DocumentDB(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CollectionName"], ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]
```

then Visual Studio gives me a compilation error:

*CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Is there any way to configure these DocumentDB attribute arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
[DocumentDB("%database%", "%collection%", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]
```

and then define settings with corresponding names (without `%`).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Just what I needed.

Comment: what is `%` used for here, is it by convention ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, I guess it's a convention

Comment: Yes, %appsetting% is a convention to pull from AppSettings. {value} is a convention to pull from "binding data" (ie, data from the trigger). This is documented more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings