# How can I set CosmosDBTrigger parameters with values from the app values stored in the Function App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, decorator

I am working on an Azure Function that will be triggered everytime a document gets updated in CosmosDB. I have already sucessfully completed it, but now I want to avoid hardcoding values inside the CosmosDBTrigger decorator.

I have already tried to reference the stored app values using '%' signs as I saw in another SO post. However, it doesn't seem to work. Post is : [Is it possible to configure Azure C# function DocumentDB attribute arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382984/is-it-possible-to-configure-azure-c-sharp-function-documentdb-attribute-argument)

Here is the solution that I am trying to get working:

```cs
 public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%LogLevelsCachingDatabaseName%",
            collectionName: "%LogLevelsCachingCollectionName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "%LogLevelsCachingDatabaseSetting%",
            LeaseCollectionName = "%LogLevelsCachingLeaseCollectionName%",
            StartFromBeginning = true
            )]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
        {
            if (input == null || input.Count <= 0) return;
```

The working solution was exactly the same, but the values between '%' were the hardcoded values.

Here is the output I have when I publish the Azure Function to Azure DevOps. Please note that the ConnectionStringSetting value is valid, since I have been able to run the Azure Function without any issue with the hardcoded value.

**Error:**

> Function (CacheLogLevels) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CacheLogLevels'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection Information for %LogLevelsCachingCollectionName% in database %LogLevelsCachingDatabaseName% with lease %LogLevelsCachingLeaseCollectionName% in database %LogLevelsCachingDatabaseName% : Unable to resolve app setting for property 'CosmosDBTriggerAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the app setting exists and has a valid value. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Unable to resolve app setting for property 'CosmosDBTriggerAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the app setting exists and has a valid value.
>   Session Id: 34dd30479d6a440caf063493bd1abc3d

Timestamp: 2019-07-17T22:35:01.376Z

And I want to use the values that comes from the Azure Function App configuration:

**Azure Function App Configuration**

[image]

Thank you so much for reading my question and have a wonderful day!

Vittorio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*ConnectionStringSettings* and *LeaseConnectionStringSetting* parameters automatically resolve values as app settings, without percent signs (see [trigger configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---configuration)):

```cs
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%LogLevelsCachingDatabaseName%",
            collectionName: "%LogLevelsCachingCollectionName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "LogLevelsCachingDatabaseSetting", // <-- remove %-signs
            LeaseCollectionName = "%LogLevelsCachingLeaseCollectionName%",
            StartFromBeginning = true
            )]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
```

Comment: That fixed my issue! So I removed the '%' from the ConnectionStringSetting, kept the '%' around the LeaseCollectionName and added the LeaseDatabaseName attribute to be the same as the databaseName's value. I also had to go in the appsettings in azure and replace the value of LogLevelsCachingDatabaseSettings to be the complete connection string instead of only the settings name!

Thank you very much!

Kindest regards,

Vittorio

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @vladimir

*ConnectionStringSettings and LeaseConnectionStringSetting parameters automatically resolve values as app settings*

There are 2 ways to do that:

1. Manually update the value via azure portal
   [image]
2. Set it via release pipeline on azure portal
   [image]

Hope it helps